# How to pass DB connection in user class

Tags: php, pdo

I know this is might be a duplicate post, however all of the examples didn't quite help me, examples like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13793165/how-to-pass-db-connection-to-another-class) im trying to pass my db connection to user class.

What am i doing wrong

i get the follow errors

```
 Undefined property: Db::$connect 

 Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object
```

Db.php

```
<?php 

error_reporting(-1);

class Db{

    private $db_host;
    private $db_user;
    private $db_name;
    private $db_pass;

    public function connect()
    {
        $this->db_host = "127.0.0.1";
        $this->db_user = "root";
        $this->db_pass = "root";
        $this->db_name = "eli9";

        try {
            $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889,dbname=eli9", 'root', 'root');
            $db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
            echo "connected \n";


        } 
        catch (PDOException $e){
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


        return $db;

    }


}
```

User.php

```
<?php

require_once 'Db.php';

class User extends Db{

    private $db;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Db();

    }


    public function signup($email, $password, $username)
    {
        try{
            $stmt = $this->db->connect->prepare("INSERT INTO users (user_email, user_pass, user_name) VALUES (:email, :password, :username) ");

            $stmt->bindparam(':email', $email);
            $stmt->bindparam(':password', $password);
            $stmt->bindparam(':username', $username);
            $stmt->execute();

        }

        catch(PDOExeception $e)
        {
            echo $e->getMessage();
        }


    }


}
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11369679/727208

Comment: You have a typo, you should be doing `$this->db->connect()->` not `$this->db->connect->`. Though you can do what you are doing in your construct, it's somewhat pointless because the answer below says, `User` has inherited the methods of `Db`

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks i understand now, thanks man

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might be wrong but I don't think you can create your user class extending your DB class and then use the DB class connection function in your constructor function.

Your user class should have inherited your DB connection which you should be able to use like

`$this->db = $this->connect();`

in your constructor function.

Comment: it works however, now i get this  `PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/eli14/User.php on line 24`

Comment: Try changing this `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;port=8889,dbname=eli9` to this `mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=eli9`. Not sure if you really need the port.

Comment: wierd, i just did that before you made that comment. Thanks abraham anyway. it works now.